# How to get computer's brand and model?

Tags: delphi, pascal

I searched a lot but I can't find the solution, I found this:

```
function GetLocalComputerName(
  NameType: TComputerNameFormat = ComputerNameDnsHostname): string;
var
  len: DWORD;
begin
  len:= 0;
  GetComputerNameEx(NameType, nil, len); //get length
  SetLength(Result, len - 1);
  if not GetComputerNameEx(NameType, PChar(Result), len) then RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

But this returns the computer's name, I want to get the brand, `Samsung` for example, and the model.

Comment: What's the "_computer_" for you? Motherboard? CPU? Most of the chips? Seller? Vendor?

Comment: This is not registered in generic windows installs. As it requires vendor specific tools to retrieve them, this is hard to impossible to do generically on bare windows. At least that was the old situation. You might be able to mine something from the UEFI partition.

Comment: On a Linux with a `sysfs` mounted at `/sys` it can be as easy as reading the contents of `/sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_vendor`; or perhaps `/sys/class/dmi/id/board_vendor`. As AmigoJack pointed out, this is really depending on your definition of “computer”. The data relies on SMBIOS functionality. It’s fairly standard on desktop computers.

Comment: Even "System Information" will only give you the model from the motherboard.  Is that what you are after ?  Look at **WMIC**.  Try it from a command line first.

Answer (score 0):

For a Windows OS you can use WMI:

```pascal
//This code was generated by the Wmi Delphi Code Creator (WDCC) Version 1.9.9.482, http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/

procedure  GetWin32_ComputerSystemProductInfo;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystemProduct','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin 
    Writeln(Format('Vendor:    %s',[String(FWbemObject.Vendor)]));// String
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Please reformat your post, please make that code actually output something (instead of empty lines only), please add comments to the code, please link to the source from which this was translated.

Comment: The direct variant (executing `WMIC.exe /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path Win32_ComputerSystemProduct GET *`, not on Windows 8 and beyond anymore) outputs only a meaningful value for the column `Vendor`, which is actually my motherboard.

Comment: @AmigoJack - For me too.

Comment: @Amigojack 
No Output ! Sorry, this was missing 
    `Writeln(Format('Vendor         %s',[String(FWbemObject.Vendor)]));// String`

My intention was first to suggest the use of Delphi WMI Code Creator, and show what sort of code you can obtain with

Comment: @SergeGirard Welcome to SO - you're able to edit your answers.

Comment: Damned, I always forgot I was able to !
I am not easy with this forum, sorry. 
And thanks for corrections